# Set Job Title in a Google Contact

Tags: c#, gdata

In a program that I'm making to add and update several Google contacts, I need to set the contact's `Job Title` field (which is available under Google's Business template in Gmail). I've tried several things - setting the `Title` property, making an extended property, setting the `Occupation` field, and so on and so forth.

```
//Didn't even show up when I checked the contact on Gmail
contact.ExtendedProperties.Add(new ExtendedProperty(splitter[1], "Job Title"));
//Caused other problems; also didn't work
contact.Title = splitter[1];
```

I figure that I probably need to

1. Set the contact's template
2. Somehow set the contact's job title there.

I've checked the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) and ran it over time and time again and done several searched on Google, and the answer has yet to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's under googlecontact->organizations. This gives you a list of organizations. Each organization has a Title property (and many others), which is what you are looking for.